# What attacks exist on ECDSA if there are more than 10 million signatures?

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, dsa, attack, elliptic-curve-generation

I am aware that there are [weaknesses in ECDSA](https://blog.trailofbits.com/2020/06/11/ecdsa-handle-with-care/) when reusing `NONCE` and I am aware that there is a [lattice attack](https://fc19.ifca.ai/preproceedings/104-preproceedings.pdf) on `ECDSA`.
Are there other ways to attack `ECDSA` when one private key has made more than *10 million signatures*?
I'm interested in the `secp256k1`, `secp256r1` elliptic curve parameters. Under what conditions can the private key in these curves be revealed if a large number of signatures were generated?

Comment: Are we talking about biased nonces? Are we talking about the collision of the $k$? Are we talking about brute force?

Comment: @kelalaka I think collision of the k & biased nonces is reusing nonces. The brute force method, I do not consider it an attack and a threat, even if there are more than 10 million signatures. I'm more interested in the list of known attacks on ECDSA if the weakness and threat to private key discovery is a large number of signatures committed by one private key? If there are alternatives like Lattice Attacks?

Comment: One can re-use nonce ignorantly or there is a bug/error on the system/library. The result is the same, however, the cause can be different.  Could you first search our site for possible scenarios?